# Custom price field not being saved on admin product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I added a custom price field to WooCommerce. The field appears as expected BUT it does not save the values entered.

My code in my `functions.php` file is:

```php
/* Add custom price field to general page */
function wc_cost_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => 'wholesaler_price', 'class' => 'wc_input_price short', 'label' => __( 'Wholesaler price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')' ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wc_cost_product_field' );

function pcc_save_custom_price( $post_id ) {
    // Grab the custom price from $_POST
    $custom_price = isset( $_POST[ 'wholesale_price' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'wholesale_price' ] ) : '';

    // grab the product
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Save the custom price using WooCommerce built-in functions
    $product->update_meta_data( 'wholesale_price', $custom_price );
    $product->save();
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'pcc_save_custom_price' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some minor mistakes, this should suffice

Also note the use of `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` to save instead of the outdated `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook

```php
/* Add custom price field to general page */
function action_woocommerce_product_options_pricing() { 
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'wholesaler_price', 
        'class' => 'wc_input_price short', 
        'label' => __( 'Wholesaler price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'action_woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 10, 0 );

// Save Fields
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    if( isset($_POST['wholesaler_price']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( 'wholesaler_price', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'wholesaler_price'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
```